# Transact SQL Query to show last update of update table for each task

Tags: sql-server, aggregate-functions

I have two tables holding tasks, and updates on each task.

```
TASK_TABLE
---
TASK_ID     TASK_SUMMARY
1           Summary of Task
2           Another task

UPDATE_TABLE
---
UPDATE_ID     TASK_ID     UPDATE_DATE     UPDATE_DESC
2             1           3/10/2016       Task was updated
3             1           7/14/2016       New update
4             2           4/04/2016       Other update
```

My end goal is to make a view of TASK_TABLE with a LATEST_UPDATE_DESC column.

The column  would query the update with the MAX(UPDATE_DATE) grouped by TASK_ID and display the corresponding UPDATE_DESC. I know how to do this in MySQL but am new to T-SQL and know that a GROUP BY requires all SELECT columns to have aggregate functions if not in the group by.

The view  would look something like this:

```
TASK_TABLE_VIEW
---
TASK_ID     TASK_SUMMARY     LATEST_UPDATE_DESC
1           Summary of Task  New Update
2           Another task     Other update
```

Can anyone recommend a solution? I am stumped right now and have tried to research a solution but had no luck.

Comment: @SeanLange Top 1 would return one record. Maybe I can use it in a subquery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    Create view vwname
    as
    select t1.task_id,t1.TASK_SUMMARY,t2.UPDATE_DESC
    from
    TASK_TABLE t1
    cross apply
    (
    select top 1 update_Desc from UPDATE_TABLE t2
    where t2.task_id=t1.task_id order by UPDATE_DATE  desc ) t2
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a cte with ROW_NUMBER.

```
with SortedResults as
(
    select t.TASK_ID
        , t.TASK_SUMMARY
        , u.LATEST_UPDATE_DESC
        , ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by t.TASK_ID order by u.UPDATE_DATE DESC) as RowNum
    from TASK_TABLE t
    join UPDATE_TABLE u on u.TASK_ID = t.TASK_ID
)

select TASK_ID
    , TASK_SUMMARY
    , LATEST_UPDATE_DESC
where RowNum = 1
```